# Proving An Asymptotic Relation Needed to Answer a Probability Problem

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

I am working on understanding problem 3.4.13 from Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples. I found a solution online that relies on the following relationship:
$$
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n j^{2-\beta}\sim \frac{n^{3-\beta}}{3-\beta}.
$$

I have no idea how you show something like this.

Could anyone give some help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{j=1}^n j^{2-\beta}$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^n x^{2-\beta} dx$, which is equal to the right side you have given. (Specifically it is the right hand sum with $h=1$.) You can then use the error estimate for the rectangle rule to prove that the difference is of lower order than $n^{3-\beta}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can approximate sums with integrals. If $f$ is an increasing function, then
$$
\int_{s=a-1}^{b} f(s)\ ds \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{s=a}^{b+1} f(s)\ ds.
$$
If $f$ is a decreasing function, then
$$
\int_{s=a}^{b+1} f(s)\ ds \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{s=a-1}^{b} f(s)\ ds.
$$
The notation $\sim$ means that the ratio of the left side and the right side tends to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity.